# Interesting computer history museum in Central Europe?

Tags: europe, museums, central-europe, geek-travel

I'm looking for a good museum that is dedicated to computer history in Central Europe. Are there any recommendations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[There is a computer museum in Paderborn Germany (North Rhine Westphalia)](http://www.computerhistory.org/brochures/companies.php?alpha=m-p&company=com-42bc20f01ad01), reportedly the largest in Europe, that was formerly the headquarter of Nixdorf Computer Corporation. It's official website is [hnf.de](http://www.hnf.de/).

Comment: Thanks. Here is the link to the museum's homepage: http://www.hnf.de/

Comment: I've been there. Highly recommended!

Answer (score 8):

The [Deutsches Museum](http://www.deutsches-museum.de/en/information/) in Munich is the world's largest science and technology museum, and it has a pretty large computer exhibition as well, including a Zuse Z3 and a Cray-1

Comment: Thanks. It's really interesting. Visited it some years ago.

Answer (score 6):

On http://www.cucm.de/blog/13/computer_museen_in_deutschland/ you find a list of German computer museums (sorry, only German). But maybe you can follow the links.

For the [Haus zur Geschichte der IBM Datenverarbeitung Sindelfingen](http://www-05.ibm.com/de/ibm/unternehmen/geschichte/museum.html) (not for computer in general, only for IBM) there is an [English Flyer](http://www-05.ibm.com/de/ibm/unternehmen/geschichte/pdf/HzG_Flyer_E-PDF.pdf).
Oldenburg has also an [English Website](http://www.computermuseum-oldenburg.de/OCM_about_gb.html)

Answer (score 3):

- There is also a [computer museum](http://www.science.uva.nl/museum/) in the Universiy of Amsterdam
- The University of Applied Sciences In Kiel(Fachhochschule Kiel) has also a [Museum](http://www.fh-kiel.de/index.php?id=computermuseum&L=1)
- [Technikum29](http://www.technikum29.de/en/) is a private museum near Frankfurt